# How to create a pointer and an instance of a structure just after it's definition

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

Is it possible to initialize in dynamic way using pointers but **just after the struct definition**?
Please at the example. I tried that but I get an exception when I try `cout << a->val << endl;`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct A{
public:
    int val = 0;
    A(){}

}*a,b,c;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){

    cout << a->val << endl;//EXCEPTION
    cout << b.val << endl;
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `a` is a null pointer, which is why dereferencing it with `->` causes an exception.

Comment: Maybe.  But maybe not.  After all, it's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
struct A
{
  // ...

} *a { new A };
```

and somewhere suitable:

```
delete a;
```

---

Generally bare pointers are not recommended, you should avoid them and if you really need pointers try to use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
struct A{
public:
    int val = 0;
    A(){}
}*a,b,c;
```

*defines* the structure `A` and *declares* three global variables, `a`, `b`, `c`.

`a` is of type 'A*' - i.e. pointer to type `A`, `b` and `c` are *instances* of type `A`.

Global variables of simple, base types (e.g. ints, pointers, etc), default to 0.

The result is equivalent to this:

```
struct A{
public:
    int val = 0;
    A(){}
};
A* a = NULL;
A b;
A c;
```

When your code then tries to use `a` without assigning a value to it, it is dereferencing a NULL pointer and crashes.